# Using Jquery to change the order of a div on page load

Tags: jquery, html

I am just curious if it is possible to take Jquery and do something where:

```
<div class="test">
<div class="test2">
```

is then flipped to:

```
<div class="test2">
<div class="test">
```

Keep in mind that both divs are displayed, neither is hidden. This doesnt do some fancy animation or anything like that, instead all it does on page load is swap the order of the divs and continues on like nothing ever happened.

Ideas?

Comment: do you want to switch classes of switch places of divs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a little convoluted but it swaps the nodes, placing it directly before .test

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cC2hH/

```
$('.test').before($('.test2').remove());
```

Comment: I guess it doesn't swap them but rather removes it and replaces it from the document.